# Tutorial/Howto for a android 5 (Material Design) contactdetail view

Tags: android, material-design

I am looking for a tutorial or a howto for a android 5 (Material Design) contact detail view. It should look like this:

[image: material design]

and with this functionality:

[image]

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Thank you sir for putting down requirement but FYI, Stackoverflow is neither a tutorial nor a code repository!

Comment: I can provide my attempts. But that doesn't look like the pictures.

Comment: What is wrong with this question? Isn't Stackoverflow a development related question answer site? Isn't this question development related? I don't understand why such questions are closed.

Answer (score 3):

you can start by reading from here 
https://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html
you have to cover recycler view,card view and custom animation to achieve that effect
update:
here's one more good link that explains the specification
http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html